# Whenever try to interpolate in angular 11 it just shows as text on webpage

Tags: angular

New to angular trying my first code and this was the first step in the tutorial. On live server using port 5500 whenever run this code or any other interpolation

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

Result on webpage: **{{title}}**

All i did was remove all the html from the app.component.html and run that code. Didn't touch the app.component.ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'intro';
}
```

Getting no errors or warning in console.
Don't know what to do to correct it. Is my syntax wrong? or any other problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the live server, follow these steps to [*serve*](https://angular.io/cli/serve) your Angular app.

1. Open a new terminal and navigate to your Angular folder.
2. Run `ng serve`.

By default, your app will be displayed at **http://localhost:4200/**.

You should see there the changes applied.

Comment: Is there any reason why you method is working but the earlier method was not working? Also thanks mate it is working now.

Comment: @KaranPatel yes running with ng serve. Runs the app via nodejs so it builds everytime you make a change. If you want to just run the files raw you need to use ng build and run them from the /dist folder.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it worked! As @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen mentioned, to run raw files you'll need to build the project (that's actually one step that you may need to do afterwards when deploying the project).